# React Class components vs Functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-16

Before `React16`, `class components` were used over `functional components` whenever there is a need to use `state` or `lifecycle methods` in your component.
In the latest release react introduced [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and [Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) using which we can use `state` and `lifecycle methods` inside our `functional components`.

So is there any reason why still the `class components` exists? Is there any cases we still have to choose `class components` over `functional`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes) you can see the cases where you will need class components

The most common case where you will need class components is if you want to make an [`ErrorBoundary`](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html), you will need a class component because you can't implement `componentDidCatch` with hooks... yet!